# How to push a commit with no label in git?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script to push commits for me that have no label (no tags, no branch, not HEAD, etc.). I want it to `push` a given commit by its hash to a remote repository, so that I can later call `checkout` on it on the remote side.

How can I do this in git? The naive `git push REMOTE HASH` gives an error like

```
fatal: HASH cannot be resolved to branch
```

I (obviously) already realize I can give a dummy label and then remove it, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Also note that I don't want a performance penalty (whether it's space/time/network/other usage); I want it to have the same performance as it would for a labeled commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pushing a commit, you must specify a remote ref to push to.  A ref is required because objects not matching a ref are by default inaccessible over many remote protocols, and as a consequence pushing such objects wouldn't be very useful.  Unreferenced objects are also subject to garbage collection, so anything you did push without a reference (were that possible) would be liable to be removed immediately.

If you want to push an arbitrary object to a remote ref, you can use the following syntax to push the given commit to the `temp` branch:

```
git push d9f6f3b6195a0ca35642561e530798ad1469bd41:refs/heads/temp
```

You can also use any arbitrary revision on the left side of the colon instead.

Comment: It would actually be quite useful to me (and I don't mind garbage collection, I can always push again), but just to confirm: so are you saying a push like this is literally impossible to do without a named ref on the remote side?

Comment: @Mehrdad: in all the standard Git protocols, yes. You could write your own transfer protocol and command(s) that let(s) you send-and-receive objects, and install this on your clients and servers. But if you're going to use `git push`, or even `git bundle` and `git fetch`, you'll need to choose a name on the `git push` or `git bundle` side. The `fetch` side of this operation may choose to change this name to some other name, or drop it and use only `FETCH_HEAD`, if you like.